# Application's Autosave functionality causing selenium script failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, exception, testng

org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: Element  is not clickable at point (856,732) because another element  obscures it

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the below options,

- As per my understanding, if we are on a webform with the auto-save functionality, then if we come out of a particular field autosave will be triggered and it will take some time for the autosave to happen. So in your case, you could try coming out of the field(i.e., by clicking outside that field using selenium) and have the code wait for some time to get the auto-save to complete.

You could use an explicit wait for this scenario. The below command will wait for a maximum of 40 seconds in order for the button to become clickable. If the element is clickable before 40 seconds it will click it. If the 40 seconds wait time gets over, then it will throw an exception.

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElementById("element-id"));
```